# 404 bad request error when integrating Google Analytic in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I am integrating Google Analytic in asp.net which is giving me error 404 bad request.I am using google anayltics v3 in which https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data is obsolute.Thats why i am using https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data but again 404 error on this line

string result = webClient.DownloadString(feedUrl);
when i debuged the code 
feedUrl= https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:UA-55271282-1&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=-ga:pageviews&start-date=2011-06-25&end-date=2011-07-25"

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        //-------------- Get Auth Token -------------------

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("accountType", "GOOGLE");
        data.Add("Email", "myEmailAddress");
        data.Add("Passwd", "******");//Passwd, not a misspell.
        data.Add("service", "analytics");
        data.Add("source", "xxxx-xxxx-xx");//Could be anything.

        byte[] bytes = webClient.UploadValues("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", "POST", data);
        string tokens = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        string authToken = extractAuthToken(tokens);

        //-------------- Get page views -------------------

        string feed = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data";

        //Required:
        string ids = "ga:UA-55271282-1";
        string metrics = "ga:pageviews";
        string startDate = "2011-06-25";
        string endDate = "2011-07-25";

        //Optional:
        string dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
        string sort = "-ga:pageviews";

        string feedUrl = string.Format("{0}?ids={1}&dimensions={2}&metrics={3}&sort={4}&start-date={5}&end-date={6}",
            feed, ids, dimensions, metrics, sort, startDate, endDate);

        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin " + authToken);
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(feedUrl);

        //-------------- Extract data from xml -------------------

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(result);
        var ns1 = "{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}";
        var ns2 = "{http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009}";

        var q = from entry in xml.Descendants()
                where entry.Name == ns1 + "entry"
                select new
                {
                    PagePath = entry.Element(ns2 + "dimension").Attribute("value").Value,
                    Views = entry.Element(ns2 + "metric").Attribute("value").Value
                };

        //-------------- Do something with data -------------------
        foreach (var page in q)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(page.PagePath + " " + page.Views);
        }
    }

//-------------- Help Method -------------------
private string extractAuthToken(string data)
{          
    var tokens = data.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);            
    return tokens.Where(token => token.StartsWith("Auth=")).Single();
}
}
```

Comment: why are you using v2.4? why aren't you using the Google-dotnet-client lib? Why aren't you using Oauth2? http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-api-v3-with-c/

Comment: i am new to this i don't know the proper libraries for this.can you please guide me

Comment: Check the link I am in the process of upgrading that tutorial I have a sample project on GitHub as well http://goo.gl/2dSRHX

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem